# jQuery copy multiple date dropdowns to hidden field

Tags: jquery

I have a form with 3 dropdown boxes to select Month/Day/Year. I need to submit the info selected in ISO 8601 format (e.g. '2012-05-30') via a hidden field. How can I use jQuery to build the date value based on what's selected in those dropdown boxes?

The HTML is something like:

```
<select name=month>
   <option>01</option>
   <option>02</option>
   <option>etc...</option>
</select>

<select name=day>
   <option>01</option>
   <option>02</option>
   <option>etc...</option>
</select>

<select name=year>
   <option>2012</option>
   <option>2013</option>
   <option>etc...</option>
</select>

<input type="hidden" name="date" value="">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to submit the info selected in ISO 8601 format (e.g.
>   '2012-05-30') via a hidden field.

```
$('#formId').submit(function(){

  var dt = $('select[name=year] option:selected').text()
      + '-' +  $('select[name=month] option:selected').text() 
      + '-' + $('select[name=day] option:selected').text();

  $('input[name=date]').val(dt);
});
```

Comment: @Nate: I answered 1 minute before him and also his answer does not account for your requirement, you want selected value of each drop down and that text of each option tag not value since your option tags have no value set and you are also not using ids for your elements. My answer is different and accounts for your current html structure.

Comment: `$('select[name=year] option:selected').text()` is same as `$('select[name=year]').val()`, isn't it? Just when no `value` is specified, but I believe @Nate should put some on its `option`s `:)` I used id, because it's quite common to see a `select[name=year]` twice in a same HTML document.

Answer (score 1):

Do it on the form submit:

```
$("#myForm").submit(function() {
    var value = $("#myYearSelect").val()
    value += "-" + $("#myMonthSelect").val()
    value += "-" + $("#myDaySelect").val();
    $("#myHiddenInput").val(value);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
     <form id="test" method="post">
    <select name="month" class="date1">
       <option value="01">January</option>
      <option value="02">February</option>
    </select>

   <select name="day" class="date1">
     <option value="01">01</option>
    <option value="02">02</option>
   </select>
  <select name="year" class="date1">
    <option value="2012">2012</option>
    <option value="2013">2013</option>
 </select>
 <input type="hidden" name="date" value="">
 <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

See the javascript in the demo.

[try the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ShWz8/3/)

Comment: This is pretty slick. Thanks for the demo

Answer (score 0):

```
var mydate = $('input[name=year]').val() + '/' +  $('input[name=month]').val() +  '/' + $('input[name=day]').val();

$('input[name=date]').val(mydate);
```